# Update/change values of NSDictionary keys stored in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, segue, nspredicate

I have an `NSArray` containing `NSDictionary`'s of client data. I am using `NSPredicate` to filter the `array` and pass it through `ViewControllers` with `segues`. I am at a stage where I would like to change some values of the keys stored in the `dictionary`. How is this achievable?

My `prepareForSegue` method

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showClients"]) {
            // Detect selected row
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            // Extract value from the Clinic_Location attribute
            NSString *cString = [[_clinicList valueForKey:@"Clinic_Location"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"Row pressed: %@", cString);

            // Set predicate where Clinic_Location equals the clinic string extracted from the selected row
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Clinic_Location == %@", cString];
            // Filter the client array using this predicate
            filteredClientArray = [dataStart filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
            NSLog(@"Filtered array: %@", filteredClientArray);
            // Reload the table
            [self.tableView reloadData];

            // Sort the array by Appt_Time in ascending order
            NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"Appt_Time" ascending:YES];
            NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
            NSArray *sortedArray = [filteredClientArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
            filteredClientArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:sortedArray];

            // Pass the newly filtered & sorted array to next view
            PCClientsViewController *pcClients = segue.destinationViewController;
            pcClients.clientArray = filteredClientArray;
        }
```

The `array` now only contains certain `dictionaries` based on this `predicate` (i.e. when user selects a row on the `TableView`, let's say `'Manchester'`, then only `dictionaries` with a `Clinic_Location` of `Manchester` get passed to the next view.

My `prepareForSegue` method on the next `TableView` is similar to the previous one, in this case my `predicate` filters the `dictionary` with a matching surname on the selected row and pushes that to the next view. Now I am left with an `array` constructed like the one below:

```
Filtered array: (
        {
        "Appointment_Attended" = Yes;
        "Appt_Time" = "2:00";
        "Client_Address_Line_1" = "Ap #452-4253 Massa. Street";
        "Client_Address_Line_2" = Montebello;
        "Client_Address_Line_3" = Hull;
        "Client_Address_Line_4" = Quebec;
        "Client_Address_Line_5" = Micronesia;
        "Client_Forename" = Veronica;
        "Client_Postcode" = 69591;
        "Client_Surname" = Ellis;
        "Client_Tel" = "(019376) 26081";
        "Clinic_Location" = Manchester;
        "Passed_To_Medical" = No;
        "Passed_To_Sol" = No;
    }
)
```

I have tried many different approaches to update specific `dictionary keys` in this `array` such as using `predicates`, but nothing seems to work. For example:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Client_Address_Line_1 == %@", [[_clientDetails valueForKey:@"Client_Address_Line_1"]objectAtIndex:0]];
NSLog(@"%@", predicate);
NSArray* filteredArray= [_clientDetails filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
[filteredArray performSelector: @selector(setValue:forKey:) withObject:self.clientAddLine1.text withObject:@"Client_Address_Line_1"];
```

No matter what I try I am continuously getting error messages such as:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x7904f590> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key
>   Client_Address_Line_1.'
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI
>   setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78774c70'
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSDictionaryI 0x7bff6eb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key
>   Client_Address_Line_1.'

It seems no matter what I do I cannot change or update any `dictionary keys` within the `array`. After hours of research, I'm beginning to wonder if this is this even possible? Am I looking at the wrong approach completely? Is there a better way to do this? After the `keys` have been changed, I need to save them back to the `array` and pass it back through `ViewControllers` also (possibly with `Unwind Segues`?) Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may only change the values for key in mutable subclasses of NSDictionary, NSDictionary itself is immutable.

so since you have changed to a mutable array, you can do the same thing for each of the dictionaries also:

```
filteredClientArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:sortedArray];
for(NSDictionary *d in [filteredClientArray copy])
{
    NSMutableDictionary * m = [d mutableCopy];
    [filteredClientArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[filteredClientArray indexOfObject:d] withObject:m];
}
```

Comment: of course mutable copy will be retained, which you will have to deal with if you aren't using arc

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So should I change all my `dictionaries` to `mutable dictionaries` at the point when the `keys` are being changed? Or should your code be implemented before the `array` gets passed to the last `ViewController`? Also I am using `ARC`.

Comment: Sorry for the double comment - I have added your code in my method when changing the data, and using my `NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Client_Address_Line_1 == %@"` code, I can successfully change the dictionary keys. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @rosshump, there is a subtle error in this strategy, where you aren't supposed to mutate a collection that you are iterating... you should make a copy of the array to iterate... there shouldn't be any problem with this in this case, but it can raise an exception... editing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think I'll need to research more about `dictionaries` to fully understand the concept. I'm still pretty new to objective-c, so apologies for my lack of knowledge! Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: mutableCopy. This saved me lot. Thanks mate.